# I'm Trying to use VTK with Qt using CMake and Visual Studio, and get this Error while building fatal error -> Byte order of target CPU unknown

Tags: cmake

My os is windows running on parallels Desktop app on Mac M2
When I Try to build the libraries I get this error

fatal  error C1189: #error:  "Byte order of target CPU unknown."

This is what I got in the console of VS when I finished installing

`274>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Release ARM64 ------ 274>Building Custom Rule C:/VTK-9.2.2/src/CMakeLists.txt ========== Build: 157 succeeded, 117 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== ========== Elapsed 11:48.565 ==========`

[image: screen of the error I got]

Comment: Which cmake version are you using?

Comment: For most people, the image is unreadable and won't be searcheable in the future.
Please include the relevant content in your question as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an old (<2.8 cmake, this can be the issue): https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13808

In any case, you might try to set the byte-order manually in your cmake file:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_BYTE_ORDER BIG_ENDIAN)
```

You could also check that `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES` only specify one architecture or all architectures shares the same byte-order.